# Solving Vuetify "v-menu" appears as fixed if parent component is inside a scrolling container

Tags: scroll, menu, vuetify.js, fixed

There is a long standing [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/795) with the `v-menu` component in Vuetify:

1. by default the popup is physically "detached" from the activator and created as a child of `v-app`, thus avoiding being clipped if some of the parent DOM nodes has `overflow: hidden` style; however, this leads to the issue that the popup behaves as "position: fixed" when the activator is inside a scrolling container - that is, it does not scroll with the activator and looks visually disconnected, just "hanging" over the page.
2. the Vuetify maintainers admit the fact and suggest using the "attach" prop - however, 9 times out of 10 when using "attach" the position of the popup is computed wrong.

After 2 hours of debugging I finally gave up on using the "attach" prop and decided to simply track the scrolling position of the parent container where the activator resides and take it into account when computing the position of the popup. I am sharing my solution to the issue below and hoping that it will be included in the mainstream Vuetify.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the patch file which solves the above issue plus a few others. Create a folder named `patches` inside your project and save the patch file as `patches/vuetify#2.6.4.patch`. Then add a new script to the `scripts` group in your `package.json`

```json
"scripts":
{
   ....
   "prepare": "custompatch"
}
```

Then run `npm -i -D custompatch` (to install the patcher for your CI/CD) and `npx custompatch` (to actually patch Vuetify in your dev environment).

```
Index: \vuetify\lib\components\VDialog\VDialog.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\components\VDialog\VDialog.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\components\VDialog\VDialog.js
@@ -43,17 +43,21 @@
     transition: {
       type: [String, Boolean],
       default: 'dialog-transition'
     },
-    width: [String, Number]
+    width: [String, Number],
+    zIndex: {
+      type: [String, Number],
+      default: 200
+    }
   },
 
   data() {
     return {
       activatedBy: null,
       animate: false,
       animateTimeout: -1,
-      stackMinZIndex: 200,
+      stackMinZIndex: this.zIndex || 200,
       previousActiveElement: null
     };
   },
 
Index: \vuetify\lib\components\VMenu\VMenu.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\components\VMenu\VMenu.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\components\VMenu\VMenu.js
@@ -120,10 +120,10 @@
       return {
         maxHeight: this.calculatedMaxHeight,
         minWidth: this.calculatedMinWidth,
         maxWidth: this.calculatedMaxWidth,
-        top: this.calculatedTop,
-        left: this.calculatedLeft,
+        top: `calc(${this.calculatedTop} - ${this.scrollY}px + ${this.originalScrollY}px)`,
+        left: `calc(${this.calculatedLeft} - ${this.scrollX}px + ${this.originalScrollX}px)`,
         transformOrigin: this.origin,
         zIndex: this.zIndex || this.activeZIndex
       };
     }
Index: \vuetify\lib\components\VSelect\VSelect.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\components\VSelect\VSelect.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\components\VSelect\VSelect.js
@@ -678,12 +678,17 @@
     },
 
     onScroll() {
       if (!this.isMenuActive) {
-        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.getContent().scrollTop = 0);
+        requestAnimationFrame(() => 
+        {
+          const content = this.getContent();
+          if (content) content.scrollTop = 0;
+        });
       } else {
         if (this.lastItem > this.computedItems.length) return;
-        const showMoreItems = this.getContent().scrollHeight - (this.getContent().scrollTop + this.getContent().clientHeight) < 200;
+        const content = this.getContent();
+        const showMoreItems = content ? this.getContent().scrollHeight - (this.getContent().scrollTop + this.getContent().clientHeight) < 200 : false;
 
         if (showMoreItems) {
           this.lastItem += 20;
         }
Index: \vuetify\lib\components\VSlideGroup\VSlideGroup.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\components\VSlideGroup\VSlideGroup.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\components\VSlideGroup\VSlideGroup.js
@@ -181,9 +181,9 @@
   },
 
   methods: {
     onScroll() {
-      this.$refs.wrapper.scrollLeft = 0;
+      if (this.$refs.wrapper) this.$refs.wrapper.scrollLeft = 0; // TMCDOS
     },
 
     onFocusin(e) {
       if (!this.isOverflowing) return; // Focused element is likely to be the root of an item, so a
Index: \vuetify\lib\components\VTextField\VTextField.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\components\VTextField\VTextField.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\components\VTextField\VTextField.js
@@ -441,8 +441,9 @@
       this.$refs.input.focus();
     },
 
     onFocus(e) {
+      this.onResize();
       if (!this.$refs.input) return;
       const root = attachedRoot(this.$el);
       if (!root) return;
 
Index: \vuetify\lib\directives\click-outside\index.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\directives\click-outside\index.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\directives\click-outside\index.js
@@ -35,10 +35,11 @@
 }
 
 function directive(e, el, binding, vnode) {
   const handler = typeof binding.value === 'function' ? binding.value : binding.value.handler;
+  const target = e.target;
   el._clickOutside.lastMousedownWasOutside && checkEvent(e, el, binding) && setTimeout(() => {
-    checkIsActive(e, binding) && handler && handler(e);
+    checkIsActive({...e, target}, binding) && handler && handler({...e, target}); 
   }, 0);
 }
 
 function handleShadow(el, callback) {
Index: \vuetify\lib\directives\ripple\index.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\directives\ripple\index.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\directives\ripple\index.js
@@ -119,9 +119,9 @@
           el.style.position = el.dataset.previousPosition;
           delete el.dataset.previousPosition;
         }
 
-        animation.parentNode && el.removeChild(animation.parentNode);
+        animation.parentNode && /* el */animation.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(animation.parentNode);
       }, 300);
     }, delay);
   }
 
Index: \vuetify\lib\mixins\detachable\index.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\mixins\detachable\index.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\mixins\detachable\index.js
@@ -28,13 +28,23 @@
     },
     contentClass: {
       type: String,
       default: ''
+    },
+    scroller:
+    {
+      default: null,
+      validator: validateAttachTarget
     }
   },
   data: () => ({
     activatorNode: null,
-    hasDetached: false
+    hasDetached: false,
+    scrollingNode: null,
+    scrollX: 0,
+    scrollY: 0,
+    originalScrollX: 0,
+    originalScrollY: 0 
   }),
   watch: {
     attach() {
       this.hasDetached = false;
@@ -42,10 +52,38 @@
     },
 
     hasContent() {
       this.$nextTick(this.initDetach);
+    },
+    isActive(val)
+    {
+      if (val)
+      {
+        if (typeof this.scroller === 'string') {
+          // CSS selector
+          this.scrollingNode = document.querySelector(this.scroller);
+        } else if (this.scroller && typeof this.scroller === 'object') {
+          // DOM Element
+          this.scrollingNode = this.scroller;
+        }
+        if (this.scrollingNode)
+        {
+          this.originalScrollX = this.scrollingNode.scrollLeft;
+          this.originalScrollY = this.scrollingNode.scrollTop;
+          this.scrollX = this.originalScrollX;
+          this.scrollY = this.originalScrollY;
+          this.scrollingNode.addEventListener('scroll', this.setScrollOffset, {passive: true});
+        }
+      }
+      else
+      {
+        if (this.scrollingNode)
+        {
+          this.scrollingNode.removeEventListener('scroll', this.setScrollOffset, {passive: true});
+        }
+        this.scrollingNode = null;
+      }
     }
-
   },
 
   beforeMount() {
     this.$nextTick(() => {
@@ -95,8 +133,12 @@
       } else {
         removeActivator(activator);
       }
     }
+    if (this.scrollingNode)
+    {
+      this.scrollingNode.removeEventListener('scroll', this.setScrollOffset, {passive: true});
+    }
   },
 
   methods: {
     getScopeIdAttrs() {
@@ -132,9 +174,13 @@
       }
 
       target.appendChild(this.$refs.content);
       this.hasDetached = true;
+    },
+    setScrollOffset(event)
+    {
+      this.scrollX = event.target.scrollLeft;
+      this.scrollY = event.target.scrollTop;
     }
-
   }
 });
 //# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
\ No newline at end of file
Index: \vuetify\lib\mixins\menuable\index.js
===================================================================
--- \vuetify\lib\mixins\menuable\index.js
+++ \vuetify\lib\mixins\menuable\index.js
@@ -96,9 +96,9 @@
   computed: {
     computedLeft() {
       const a = this.dimensions.activator;
       const c = this.dimensions.content;
-      const activatorLeft = (this.attach !== false ? a.offsetLeft : a.left) || 0;
+      const activatorLeft = (this.attach !== false ? this.getActivatorLeft() : a.left) || 0;
       const minWidth = Math.max(a.width, c.width);
       let left = 0;
       left += activatorLeft;
       if (this.left || this.$vuetify.rtl && !this.right) left -= minWidth - a.width;
@@ -117,9 +117,9 @@
       const a = this.dimensions.activator;
       const c = this.dimensions.content;
       let top = 0;
       if (this.top) top += a.height - c.height;
-      if (this.attach !== false) top += a.offsetTop;else top += a.top + this.pageYOffset;
+      if (this.attach !== false) top += this.getActivatorTop(); else top += a.top + this.pageYOffset;
       if (this.offsetY) top += this.top ? -a.height : a.height;
       if (this.nudgeTop) top -= parseInt(this.nudgeTop);
       if (this.nudgeBottom) top += parseInt(this.nudgeBottom);
       return top;
@@ -130,10 +130,13 @@
     },
 
     absoluteYOffset() {
       return this.pageYOffset - this.relativeYOffset;
+    },
+
+    windowContainer() {
+      return typeof this.attach === 'string' ? document.querySelector(this.attach) || document.body : typeof this.attach === 'object' ? this.attach : document.body;
     }
-
   },
   watch: {
     disabled(val) {
       val && this.callDeactivate();
@@ -274,19 +277,19 @@
     },
 
     getInnerHeight() {
       if (!this.hasWindow) return 0;
-      return window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
+      return this.attach !== false ? this.windowContainer.clientHeight : window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
     },
 
     getOffsetLeft() {
       if (!this.hasWindow) return 0;
-      return window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
+      return this.attach !== false ? this.windowContainer.scrollLeft : window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
     },
 
     getOffsetTop() {
       if (!this.hasWindow) return 0;
-      return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
+      return this.attach !== false ? this.windowContainer.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     },
 
     getRoundedBoundedClientRect(el) {
       const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
@@ -368,19 +371,38 @@
       this.sneakPeek(() => {
         if (this.$refs.content) {
           if (this.$refs.content.offsetParent) {
             const offsetRect = this.getRoundedBoundedClientRect(this.$refs.content.offsetParent);
-            this.relativeYOffset = window.pageYOffset + offsetRect.top;
+            this.relativeYOffset = (this.attach !== false ? this.windowContainer.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset) + offsetRect.top;
             dimensions.activator.top -= this.relativeYOffset;
-            dimensions.activator.left -= window.pageXOffset + offsetRect.left;
+            dimensions.activator.left -= (this.attach !== false ? this.windowContainer.scrollLeft : window.pageXOffset) + offsetRect.left;
           }
 
           dimensions.content = this.measure(this.$refs.content);
         }
 
         this.dimensions = dimensions;
       });
+    },
+
+    getActivatorTop() {
+      let result = 0;
+      let elem = this.getActivator();
+      while (elem && elem !== this.windowContainer && this.windowContainer.contains(elem)) {
+        result += elem.offsetTop;
+        elem = elem.offsetParent;
+      }
+      return result;
+    },
+
+    getActivatorLeft() {
+      let result = 0;
+      let elem = this.getActivator();
+      while (elem && elem !== this.windowContainer && this.windowContainer.contains(elem)) {
+        result += elem.offsetLeft;
+        elem = elem.offsetParent;
+      }
+      return result;
     }
-
   }
 });
 //# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Great solution as it fixes the scrolling issue. However, the menu position doesn't update if I add content below or above it. Say I add a box above the menu. The element it is attached to will move down, but the menu position stays fixed. Any idea on how to address this?

Comment: You will have to use a MutationObserver and watch for mutations below the DOM node where the menu is attached to. In my solution I get the scrolling position of the attachment node only at menu activation - so it does not take into account DOM changes while the menu is visible.

Comment: @kjmj I've updated the patch to take into account the "attach" prop - so if you attach to the DIV container which is scrolling - it should solve your problem. I haven't tested the behavior when you provide both "attach" and "scroller" props - in my projects I am using either one or the other, not both.